# Return attributes from list using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm currently AJAX using .NET Core. I'm trying to do very basic thing. Populate a list of item and then display every item in `<li>`. The problem is that the list im sending is of type  which comes from my database. Therefore if you scroll to my javascript code, after execution each `<li>` item is 'undefined'. I'm pretty sure this happens because I'm sending the whole object.

So what I need is to have another loop in my $.each to select PersonId, PersonName, PersonAddress and display them in the row.

As a newbie in javascript and Ajax I'm really struggling here unable to find any good tutorial for asp.net core.

Thanks a lot for any advice

My model is:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string PersonAddress { get; set; }
}
```

My Index method:

```
public JsonResult OnGetList()
{
    List<Models.Person> list = new List<Models.Person>();

    foreach (var item in _context.Person.ToList())
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return new JsonResult(list);
}
```

Data from the DB look like this:

```
PersonId PersonName PersonAddress
1        Martin     New York
2        Sam        New Jersey
3        Eli        Ohio
```

My view:

```html
<div id="dvItems" style="font-size:24px;">
</div>
```

Javascript embedded in the bottom of the view:

```html
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Person?handler=List",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var dvItems= $("#dvItems");
            dvItems.empty();
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                var $tr = $('<li>').append(item.PersonId + "with name " + item.PersonName + "living in" + item.PersonAddress).appendTo(dvItems);
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of the JSON `response` that comes back from `OnGetList()`?

Comment: You can check your response using the Developer Tools in your browser. Open it using F12 (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) and go to the Network tab, find your XHR request and check the structure of your response.

Comment: response is `[{personId: 25, personName: "martin", personAddress: "strnadova"},…]
0: {personId: 25, personName: "martin", personAddress: "strnadova"}
personAddress: "strnadova"
personId: 25
personName: "martin"
1: {personId: 26, personName: "barbora", personAddress: "strnadova"}
personAddress: "strnadova"
personId: 26
personName: "barbora"
2: {personId: 27, personName: "vikca", personAddress: "strnadova"}
personAddress: "strnadova"
personId: 27
personName: "vikca"`

Comment: are you `<li>`s surrounded by `<ul>`?

Comment: @sabotero - no it is not, but the html part is working I can see the `<li>` dots there, they are just empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is difference in writing

```
var $tr = $('<li>').append(item.PersonId + "with name " + item.PersonName + "living in" + item.PersonAddress).appendTo(dvItems);
```

and

```
var $tr = $('<li>').append(item.personId + "with name " + item.personName + "living in" + item.personAddress).appendTo(dvItems);
```

All the attributes written in CamelCase on the 'Entity Framework' side should have the first letter in lowercase.

Stupid me...

Thanks everybody for hitting me back tho.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce current code.

Your URL may incorrect and you should allow get in return JSON `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        public JsonResult OnGetList()
        {
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();


            foreach (var item in _context.Person.ToList())
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }

            //return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           return Json(list); // if you use NET Core
        }
}
```

In your Index.cshtml change url to `url: "Person/OnGetList"`

```
<div id="dvItems" style="font-size:24px;">
</div>
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/OnGetList",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var dvItems = $("#dvItems");
            dvItems.empty();
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                var $tr = $('<li>').append(item.PersonId + "with name " + item.PersonName + "living in" + item.PersonAddress).appendTo(dvItems);
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for hitting me back - As I stated in the beggining I'm using .net Core, `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` was deprecated in .net core 1.0 and I cannot use it

Comment: use can use this return Json(list)

Comment: I don't think I can use  `return Json(list)`. What I can use is return `new JsonResult(list);` which is exactly what I'm using. Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the original question, but it is worth mentioning:

You should (must?, for security reasons) create a DTO in the server side (`c#`) that contains exactly what you want to show on the client side (`javascript`, `html`).

You could create something like:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name {get; }
    public string Address { get;}

    public PersonDto(string name, string address)
    {
       Name = name;
       Address = address;
    }
}
```

then change your code like this:

```
public JsonResult OnGetList()
{
    var list = new List<PersonDto>();

    foreach (var item in _context.Person.ToList())
    {
        list.Add(new PersonDto(item.PersonName, item.PersonAddress));
    }

    return new JsonResult(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I had no idea I should implement  this security feature. It is something I will be definitely doing in the future!

Answer (score 0):

With the table structure provided I assume the class to be something like -

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public string PersonName { get; set; }

        public string  PersonAddress { get; set; }

    }
```

Which results in a JSon result as -

```
[{PersonId: 1, PersonName: "Person1", PersonAddress: "Charlotte"},
{PersonId: 2, PersonName: "Person2", PersonAddress: "Chicago"},
{PersonId: 3, PersonName: "Person3", PersonAddress: "Nashville"}]
```

I have used an MVC action to mimic your scenario. It should not be much different in your case.

```
public JsonResult Person()
        {
            var personArray = new Person[]
            {
                new Person(){ PersonId = 1, PersonName="Person1", PersonAddress ="Charlotte" },
                new Person(){ PersonId = 2, PersonName="Person2", PersonAddress ="Chicago" },
                new Person(){ PersonId = 3, PersonName="Person3", PersonAddress ="Nashville" }
            };

            return Json(personArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        }
```

Other things you might want to check are, if there is a difference in the class structure. Like, a custom name specified for JSon serializer. Or if these elements are enclosed in some other objects in the class.

Hope this gives some clue.

Comment: As I stated in my question - I'm using .net core, therefore `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` can't be use as it was deprecated in asp.net core 1.0.